# Is parameter evaluation order guraanteed in scala?

Tags: scala, function, parameter-passing

I know it is guaranteed to be executed left-to-right in Java, but how about Scala? I have a method that accepts an array and a limit of readable bytes:

```
def scanArray(limit: Int, ba: Array[Byte]) = { }
```

I also have a method which accepts an array, fills it with some data and return the number of bytes it filled:

```
def fillArray(ba: Array[Byte]): Int = {...}
```

The question is whether it is okay to call `scanArray` as follows:

```
val ba = new Array[Byte](16)
scanArray(fillArray(ba), ba)
```

Is the behavior guaranteed? Or it is not guaranteed by the Scala Spec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The evaluation order is described in [6.6 "Function Applications"](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#function-applications). Basically, it's the same as in Java:

> Evaluation of f(e1,…,en) usually entails evaluation of f and e1,…,en in that order.

that is,

```
({println("f"); (_: Int) + (_: Int)})(
  {println("e1"); 40},
  {println("e2"); 2}
)
```

will first print `"f"`, then `"e1"`, then `"e2"`, and finally compute `f(e1, e2)`, which is `42`.

This simple basic rule is not applicable in all situations, though. For example, if you use named arguments, and change the order of those arguments, then it is not the order in the definition of the method that is important, but the order in which you pass the named arguments at the invocation site. For example,

```
def foo(a: Int, b: Int): Unit = {}

foo(
  b = { println("b"); 1 },
  a = { println("a"); 2 }
)
```

will print `"b"` *before* it prints `"a"`, even though `a` comes before `b` in the argument list of `foo`. The exact rules are described in [6.6.1 "Named and default arguments"](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#named-and-default-arguments).

To answer the question about your concrete example: `fillArray(ba)` is guaranteed to be evaluated before `ba`, so your code seems OK. Actually, in your particular example, it wouldn't really matter, since `ba` is a `val` anyway. It points to the same array before and after the invocation of `fillArray`.